# High use of RAM and CPU, I have a idea why occur, but I don't know solve good it

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, internet, ram, cpu

It occurs that when I use Internet (Google Chrome or Mozilla) on Ubuntu and I have activity normally as to check Facebook or see a YouTube video, my cumputer uses too memory RAM until 100% principaly, or sometimes it use 100% of CPU, although before it didn't occur as now it happen. Its characterics are 4 GB of RAM, its proccesor is a Intel® Celeron(R) CPU 1017U @ 1.60GHz × 2. I didn't install software of PPA, since too much time, so it wouldn't can be the problem, or for that reason I think that it doesn't.

The reason of why, with Google Chrome or Mozilla, it begins this problem a time until today, I wouldn't be able to explain it, and I don't know solve it, except to reformat it, but I have various academics programs, as Xilinx ISE with PATH, and others which are expensive to install, and I would like to know better the problem, and solve it of practical way or, would there be a way that the problem was another? If I am on page without constant exchange of dates as this page, my computer don't arrive until 100% of RAM or CPU, but it can use more memory than I used to check.

Comment: Google Chrome tends to use a lot of ram. Could you check what the RAM usage is when using Mozilla vs Google Chrome? Could you also post what your idle RAM usage is?

Comment: When you are in Google Chrome press <Shift>+<Esc> to show which specific tabs are using the most RAM and CPU. See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/837873/xubuntu-16-04-running-slow-on-core-2-duo-4gb-ram-ssd-and-nvidia-9700-gts/840287#840287